# Perform an action after clicking on the link

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript, I need to perform an action after clicking on the link. For example, we have two pages A and B On page A, I perform a JavaScript action (filling in the text field and clicking on the button), there is a transition to page B. Here, too, you need to perform some JavaScript action, such as clicking on a link. Here is an example that only works on page A, when the transition occurs, the rest of the code seems to be erased, this is not a fact, but my guesses

```
document.getElementById('story').value='Титаник';
document.querySelector('body > div.wrapper > div.header > div.header44 > div.search_panel > span > form > button').click();
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[1].click();
```

Or another example, Follow the link and fill in the field there, which also does not work

```
window.location.href='http://www.ganjawars.ru/login.php'
function F() {
document.getElementsByName('login')[0].value = 'login';
document.getElementsByName('pass')[0].value = 'password';
}
 onload= F ()
```

How do I perform an action after clicking on a link?

Comment: by action if you mean running some code from A on the B, you can not but you can put some args in url so the B will know and run the desire code, or you can get the link event and preventDefault then do the code and then redirect to B

Comment: I think this is the soluction, look this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754851/

Comment: nullqube, yes i mean running some code from A on the B. please show me an example 
 by using my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session storage is actually the easiest solution, providing that you only want to navigate to a different page on the same website. This breaks when you close the browser or navigate to a new website.

```
story = document.getElementById('story').value='Титаник';
sessionStorage.setItem("story", story);
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[1].click();
```

and on the other page:

```
story = sessionStorage.getItem("story");
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, JavaScript does not work like this. The variables that you store on page A, will be gone, when you navigate to page B.

Possible solutions:

- One-page website
- jQuery post the variables to another page.
- PHP Sessions
- Cookies

Comment: is sessionStorage help me? please show me an example by using my code

Comment: Yes, that should do it. I actually wasn't aware of that.